# Categorize command types

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So, with my current setup, I have all of my commands under a commands folder, with my command handler looking like this:

```
//Command Handler
try {



    // Bonus: Auto-Reload
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./commands/${cmd}.js`)];

    // Options
    let ops = {
        ownerID: ownerID,
        active: active
    }

    let commandFile = require(`./commands/${cmd}.js`);
    commandFile.run(client, message, args, ops);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish now is to have these commands categorized under separate folders such as ./commands/Moderation or ./commands/General

Would I need to remake the command handler or is there coding that I can add to it to make it work how I'm wanting it to.

Comment: If you want a better command management, you could try using `discord.js-commando`: it's a framework published by Discord.js itself that makes it easier to load/unload commands, create help commands and other stuff like that. If you want to take a look at it, go to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/general/welcome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a developer library called commando. It makes the whole process of adding commands easier. Here are the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/general/welcome)